# InputFilter fails to make first character keep uppercase after dots character

Tags: android, android-input-filter

Cannot understand why when user input bachelor format like `"B.Com"`.

I want to get `"B.com"` - `c` letter is lower case.

But I'm getting: `"B.Com"` - `C` letter is capital

Here is my code:

```
InputFilter value = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int dstart, int dend) {
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            String letterOne = source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase();
            if(Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z.? ]*")) {
                return source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase()+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
            }
            return letterOne+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your current code in `for` statement may be reduced

```
String letterOne = source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase();
if(Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z.? ]*"))
{
    return source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase()+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
}
return letterOne+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
```

inside `if` statement you have `source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase()`, which is exacly same as `letterOne`, so we can reduce some code

```
String letterOne = source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase();
if(Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z.? ]*"))
{
    return letterOne+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
}
return letterOne+source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
```

now it is clearly visible that `if` statement contains same `return` as last `return` in method, so it may be reduced again to:

```
String letterOne = source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase();
return letterOne + source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
```

in above code you are not using `i` at all, so whole `for` statement is useless and `filter` may by shorted to:

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned spanned, int dstart, int dend) {
    if (start <= end) return null;
    String letterOne = source.subSequence(0,1).toString().toUpperCase();
    return letterOne + source.subSequence(1,end).toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

there is no `.`-present checking code, no uppercasing any other letter than first... you are always returning same `String` as `source` with first letter uppercased and all other lowercased

you may try to use [indexOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#indexOf(int,%2520int)) method for checking if dot is present in whole `String sourceAsString` (convert from `CharSequence source`), if yes then use [split](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#split(java.lang.String)) method for making array with two `String`s - make first letter uppercase in both words and join them `String properlyFormatted = firstWord + "." + secondWord;`

PS. be aware that `split` method takes REGEX as param and `"."` in REGEX means "any letter", so use escaping like this: `split("\\.")`

Comment: i have to try it before "there is no...". but, it can' effective when edittext have a value and user want to delete a word before

Comment: what do you want to try "before 'there is no...'"? this is same code as yours, works exacly the same... (so: wrong, logic problem, not in code) also what do you mean by 'it can' effective when' - thats not in english for shure...

Comment: i'm sorry about my grammar. but, after i try not to use for in source.charAt(i). it will be crash if in edittext have a value. for example in edittext have a value "Michael Fernando". and if i want change "Michael Setiawan" it can't because it need delete "Fernando". and then i don't get it how to implement indexOf in if condition. can you have explain more clearly about check dots value from inputFilter?

Comment: `boolean sourceContainsDot = ((String) source).indexOf(".") >= 0;` - thats how you may check that `source` contains dot. I honestly don't get what do you want to achieve and what results you are expecting to be returned by `filter` method...

Comment: i see. i can try it. thank you for help me about my issue.

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting my answer if helpful :) good luck!